My llama2 model is talking to itself asking question and answering it to them using Conversational retrieval chain
I was implementing RAG on a document with using the LLama2 model but my model is asking questions to itself and answering it to them.
llm = LlamaCpp(model_path=model_path,
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=2000,
    top_p=0.1,
    n_ctx=2048,
    
)

qa_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm,
    vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 2}), 
 )

chat_history = []  
while True:
    query = input('Prompt: ') 
    if query.lower() in ["exit", "quit", "q"]:  
        print('Exiting')
        sys.exit()
    result = qa_chain({'question': query, 'chat_history': chat_history})  
    print('Answer: ' + result['answer'] + '\n')
    chat_history.append((query, result['answer']))

I tried most online solutions but most of them doesnt use this way
